# Error Java.io.IOException for Admob on app

Tags: java, android

I would put admob adverts in my app, I did everything correctly but when I try to export the .apk:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

My "proguard-project" is:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties

# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#

# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.

# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified

# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard

# include property in project.properties.
#


# For more details, see

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html



# Add any project specific keep options here:


# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following

# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface

# class:


# -keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview  {

   public *;

}


# AdMob Support
-keep class com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.** 
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Any help?
Is the first time that i write in this blog, I hope I do not have anything wrong

EDIT:
there are also 2 warnings

```
    :app:proguardRelease
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: Are there any "above warnings"?

Comment: yes, look the first post :)